# php function not working same statistics on results

Tags: javascript, php

hello i need help about one function i try to explain:

this is the code:

```
// here user-a START // 
function get_car_speed_a($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT speed FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$urow[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['speed'];
}

function get_car_stability_a($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT stability FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$urow[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['stability'];
}

function get_car_acceleration_a($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT acceleration FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$urow[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['acceleration'];
}
// here user-a END //   



// here user-b START // 
function get_car_speed_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT speed FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid2'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['speed'];
}

function get_car_stability_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT stability FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid2'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['stability'];
}

function get_car_acceleration_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT acceleration FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid2'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['acceleration'];
}
// here user-b END //
```

and this is the code where recall the function:

```
    // battle function start//

    $apoints = get_car_speed_a($useracar) + get_car_stability_a($useracar) + get_car_acceleration_a($useracar);
    $bpoints = get_car_speed_b($userbcar) + get_car_stability_b($userbcar) + get_car_acceleration_b($userbcar);


    // battle function end//
```

the problem is easy in the website when i make the battle with user a vs user b it dont take the correct speed,stability and accelleration  so pratically the user b (the enemy) ever lose…

someone can help me? thank you so much
regards
Amy

Comment: It is not clear what your problem actually is, apart from coding the same query 3 times for each user when one would do.

Comment: hello thanks for answer pratically im tryng to make this system example user A vs user B the battle have to take the data from speed, stability and acceleration from the car so this is the screenshot of the sql table fan4free.com/xrace/screenshot20.png the problem is the function dont take the correct datas from user a and user b the battle works but both users have the same stats and this is wrong becouse in this case user b have to won check the image http://fan4free.com/xrace/screenshot21.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the "b" functions you declared $carid and use $carid2 in the sql, change this:

```
// here user-b START // 
function get_car_speed_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT speed FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['speed'];
}

function get_car_stability_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT stability FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['stability'];
}

function get_car_acceleration_b($carid)
{
    $sqle = mysql_query("SELECT acceleration FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$row2[id]' AND carid='$carid'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);
    return $row1['acceleration'];
}
// here user-b END //
```

And check the variables $urow['id'] and $row2['id'] used as userid and $carid, if they has the correct value

**UPDATE**

You can put together the functions into one

```
function get_car_info($userid, $carid)
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT speed, stability, acceleration FROM `user_cars` WHERE userid='$userid' AND carid='$carid'");
    return mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
```

And get the result like this

```
$carinfoA = get_car_info($useridA, $caridA);
$carinfoB = get_car_info($useridB, $caridB);

$apoints = $carinfoA['speed'] + $carinfoA['stability'] + $carinfoA['acceleration'];
$bpoints = $carinfoB['speed'] + $carinfoB['stability'] + $carinfoB['acceleration'];
```

I created the table you sent and tested, here the result was correct.

If the error persists, the error should be in another part of the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer i try but nothing change :/ here have the sql table image http://fan4free.com/xrace/screenshot20.png

Comment: thanks jairo i try this new code but nothing :/ the problem is the function dont take the correct datas from user a and user b the battle works but both users have the same stats and this is wrong becouse in this case user b have to won check the image please http://fan4free.com/xrace/screenshot21.jpg any other suggestions? we can use example "Active" and not carid? thanks for your patience ;)

Comment: In this case is better debug the code from the function that get the data from the database and follow the functions called until found the error. If you don't have some debug tool, just a var_dump can work fine. First check the sql code before perform the query, copy it and execute in your database manager, check if they get the same data and if the sql is with the correct userid/carid, check the values returned by get_car_info, and check the result of the sum (speed + stability + acceleration), and keep move forward until got the incorrect value, that is what I would do.